# alert dialog is not working in my flutter torch project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

`AlertDialog` is not working in my project code link is added
https://github.com/alikthehacker/Flutter_Torch/issues/1#issue-448532152

Comment: All you needed is a `MaterialApp` widget at the root, so the first line of my answer solved your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend you to update your question by adding more details. It helps you to get more attention to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full working code.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: new MyApp())); // this is what you need

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _hasFlash = false;
  bool _isOn = false;
  double _intensity = 1.0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  initPlatformState() async {
    bool hasFlash = await Lamp.hasLamp;
    print("Device has flash ? $hasFlash");
    setState(() { _hasFlash = hasFlash; });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/chocolate_pic.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation:  10 ,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          title: Text('Flutter Torch'),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.info,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                showinfo(context);
              }
          ),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 150.0,
                  height: 40.0,
                  child  : new RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Flash is on: $_isOn'),
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      elevation: 10.0,
                      splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                      onPressed:  _turnFlash,
                      textColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
                  ),
                ),
                new Text('Device has flash: $_hasFlash',),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void showinfo(BuildContext context){
    var alertDialog = AlertDialog(
      title: Text('About Flutter Torch'),
      content: Text('app made by alik kumar ghosh'),
    );
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return alertDialog;
        }
    );
  }
  Future _turnFlash() async {
    _isOn ? Lamp.turnOff() : Lamp.turnOn(intensity: _intensity);
    var f = await Lamp.hasLamp;
    setState((){
      _hasFlash = f;
      _isOn = !_isOn;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this will not work in this scaffold is not reachable

Comment: OK, can you post the code where it is not working, because I used your github full code and it is 100% working according to your code.